# Input vs Span HTML

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have simple input group and works great.

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<td class="form-group">
  <div class="col-xs-7 input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><span><b>+49</b></span></span>
    <input name="newMobileNumber" validator="/^(\d{11})$/" maxlength="11" id="newMobileNumber" validator-invoke="watch" validator-error="fehlerhafte Mobilfunknummer-Eingabe" ng-model="vm.MobileChangeData.NewMobileNumber" class="form-control" placeholder="Neue Mobilfunknummer"
      required>
  </div>
</td>
```

But I want a span in front of the +49 instead of the input.

I tried:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<td>
  <div class="col-xs-7">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><span><b>+49</b></span></span>
    <span>3124214214125</span>
  </div>
</td>
```

But everything is messed up.

Any idea?

Comment: **<div class="col-xs-7">** should also have class *input-group* and you need to style the spans.

Comment: you removed a lot of classes ... keep everything and simply change input with span

Comment: I am not familiar with the bootstrap CSS but I believe that is the problem. Locate the CSS for the specific `<span>`-element. That is where your problem is.

Answer (score 3):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<td>
  <div class="col-xs-7 input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><span><b>+49</b></span></span>
    <span class="form-control">3124214214125</span>
  </div>
</td>
```

Comment: almost perfect but it looks like an input

Comment: This is the default class of bootstrap, if you want to change a look, then you have to do it with custom css.

Answer (score 0):

because you have not added `input-group` in parent `div`

see bellow updated code :

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<td>
  <div class="col-xs-7 input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><span><b>+49</b></span></span>
    <span>3124214214125</span>
  </div>
</td>
```